# Arabic language is not showing in Invoice PDF its showing squares instead magento 2

Tags: php, magento2.2.3

I have a arabic store in magento 2. When I am trying to print invoice from magento  admin it's not supporting Arabic language it's showing squares all over Arabic language. I do not want to add any extension. Is there any simple technique without installing or creating any extension

Answer (score 0):

you can use this language pack

https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-arabic-language-pack